# How to get specific columns based on different Enum types in Mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, enums

I have a Enum column - for example: deviceType; in a table with 8 different values for the enum.
How to get columns - for example - imeiId and macId; based on the values.
For example, get ImeiId based on 4 enum values,
and get MacId based on other 4 enum values.
Note: All columns are in the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN deviceType IN ('a','b','c','d') THEN imeiId
            WHEN deviceType IN ('e','f','g','h') THEN maclId
       END AS deviceId
FROM mytable ...
```

Read about the [CASE expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case).